# Pagination IE - webpage jumps out of the screen (left)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, css, ie

When I use pagination I get a strange behavior in IE (10). The whole page jumps to the left (out of the screen), see picture below

[image]

I don't get any horizontal scroll. But if I mark a line the screen goes back to normal!

When I get this error and then hard refresh (CTRL+F5) nothing happends .. but if I copy the link to another tab I get the correct view!

Comment: We see only a glimpse of the UI (the mail and outline buttons) .. I presume it is the SharePoint Online Modern Experience UI.. if so, only Microsoft can fix it, as no custom branding is allowed in Modern Experiences

Comment: This is SharePoint 2013 On-Prem that we've redesigned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this behavior does not occur with the standard SP masterpages it definitely is your custom branding.

Your CTRL-F5 remark could suggest a file caching issue.

Taking a wild stab I would say that right column is about the width of the quicklaunch.. check all CSS on `id="contentBox"`

Comment: I found the issue. it was custom code that manage to change it ..